# Get the last cell with a value in a selection Excel C#

Tags: c#

I want to locate the last cell with a value from the selection made by a user in Excel.

When running the code below the `lastCell` variable returns the last cell in the sheet instead of the last cell in the selection.

I have no idea why this is happening as I'm telling the `lastCell` to use my selection.

Any information would be appreciated.

My code is as follows.

```
 Excel.Range selectedRange = excelApp.Selection;
 Excel.Worksheet ws = excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
 Excel.Range lastCell = selectedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);  
 var newSelectedRange = ws.Cells.Range[selectedRange.Item[1, 1], lastCell];
```

Comment: Search for the "UsedRange" property

Comment: @Romka the UsedRange property is only available as a property from the worksheet. I want to use the selection and find the used range from within the selection. If there is a way of doing so could you please advise?

Comment: Maybe with checking cells' Value2 property ; but I had bad experience with Excel automation, be careful about cells formats, formulas etc., cell may be "empty" from a user point of view but by code you'll get something != null because of formula.
If you find the right test to apply against a cell to check wether it's really "not used", you may find the "selected used range" with a dichotomy algorithm, for instance (to not loop other all single cell)